# Using the npm version of a jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have been working with the excellent [noUISlider jQuery plugin](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/) and now I want to start using [the npm version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nouislider-browser) as I am moving my JS to use node and browserify.

However I don't understand how to adapt my code to work with the npm version, and I don't understand why there is no documentation about this. Am I missing something basic about how node works?

I have run `npm install --save nouislider-browser`. Now here's my JS:

```
    var slider = require('nouislider-browser');

    $("#slider-date").noUiSlider({
        start: [20, 80],
        connect: true,
        range: {
            'min': 0,
            'max': 100
        }
    });
```

This does not error on the `var slider` line, but it errors on the `$("#slider-date").noUiSlider({...` line, saying `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).noUiSlider is not a function`.

I guess there's some way to set up the slider using the `slider` object, but how? There isn't anything in the [npm package documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nouislider-browser) about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index.js file in the NPM is empty except for this comment:

```
// placeholder, so require.resolve('xxx-browser') gives root path.
```

So I think you'll need to do this instead:

```
require('nouislider-browser/jquery.nouislider');
```

BTW I don't think you need the `var slider =`.

Comment: Thanks! I've amended it as you suggest, but now get `Uncaught RangeError: noUiSlider`. Progress since it now believes `.noUISlider()` exists, but not progress since this is the hello world example from the documentation. Any ideas?

Comment: Amending it to `range: [0, 100]` gets rid of the error (I'm not sure why since this is very different from all the documentation), but the slider itself is invisible with height 0. Do I also need to import the CSS separately?

Comment: More general question: how are we meant to know how to work with npm packages like this? Is this a case of "read up on the fundamentals of npm and then you'll know where to look in the code"?

Comment: It should be the same code as the strictly client-side version (and, after it loads, it's initialized in the same way - by being added to the `$.fn` namespace)...just to be sure, I would try to get it working with the client-side version first, then use the browserify version again. I haven't worked with that specific plugin so I don't know about the specific issue.

Comment: Most NPMs are better documented. It seems this one is using a technique borrowed from somewhere else but it's not clear what that convention is.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I actually ended up using this approach, I think maybe the npm package was out of date: http://blog.npmjs.org/post/112064849860/using-jquery-plugins-with-npm